# Wordpress or not?

Tags: wordpress

What is / are the practical differences between creating a Wordpress based website and a normal html5 based site - from a siteowners perspective?

I know a wee bit of html and css and would like to make a website for myself (promoting my freelance services), using either a Wordpress theme or a plain HTML5+CSS3 site template. But I have little or no idea about Wordpress. So, I am unable to decide.

My worry is that, if I use a Wordpress theme - I may have to upgrade or change it continually to keep up with the upgrades of main Wordpress itself. Is this correct? I want to create my site once and then leave it as it is, not worrying about or touching it for a few years - let's say 5 or more! My question is, is this possible? Will my site / pages / theme become obsolete, unusable, broken, error-prone, dysfunctional or under-performing - due to updates / upgrades of Wordpress itself during this period? This is not clear to me.

Comment: Sorry generally questions that involve positives and negatives debates are opinionated and something we try and avoid. Also recommendations of services, software and resources are off topic such as CMS suggestions. However please feel free to ask these type of questions in our [Chat Channel](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/524/webmasters).

Comment: It's alright, bybe. :-)

Comment: @byby it's true that his question is pretty much opinionated. But basically he asks if it's the right way to use a cms especially Wordpress for a website that's not gonna get too many updates once it's done. And if there are any security reasons for picking either static HTML or Wordpress. I am new here too, but in my eyes it's a reasonable question that just needs a proper formulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the advantages of WordPress are, as for any other CMS(anything referring to WordPress below is true for most other CMS as well), that you can change your site within minutes, so basically if you do not want to do so, a static HTML site is fine for you. Probably even better than that, as you do not need a database, no PHP, which boosts your overall website performance, and every technology needs updates and has potential security issues.

To your second part of the question: Nearly all themes that are 3-4 years old for WordPress still work on current versions of WordPress. They only have two flaws. First they do not offer every new feature added during the time. And second, they simply look outdated, best example compare [TwentyTen](http://wordpress.org/themes/twentyten) with [TwentyForteen](http://wordpress.org/themes/twentyfourteen). So basically the answer for that will be: You can keep a website with WordPress for that time without touching it, even if you install all core updates during that time. The performance will not change, but it will look outdated.

But you definitely should not do so! You want to sell your freelancing services, would you hire someone with a 3-5 year old website? Or if he offers you a 5 year old flyer which has outdated content or design? I worked in agencies and most websites where the customer relies on it, are maintained over the time, and in most cases get a facelift or even a complete relaunch at least every 2 years. Website designs are a bit like fashion, they change, a website that looks cool today will in most cases look old in 5 years.

**Conclusion**

If you really do not want to change it, I'd propose you use static HTML. But reconsider if you really do not want to change it. As a freelancer you have projects you might want to add to your showcase. Your address might change, you might get a new cellphone number. You might want to change your portfolio, post a new image or whatever. And changing these things on a WordPress site is not more complicated than posting your question here.

Comment: Great answer Christoph and makes a lot of sense! Opinion or not :)

Comment: Final question, how easy or difficult it is to (opinion again!) edit or tweak Wordpress pages/sites at the code level for a novice, and is that ever necessary? I am not a web developer or programmer, but I do understand html and css moderately and a wee bit of javascript. Is this enough for tweaking it at source level if necessary, or do I need to learn a lot of new things? My profession is different and although I am interested in learning a little extra, but can't devote too much time to that end.

Comment: I am asking this, because in my previous experiences with "WYSIWYG html editors" - I always needed to tweak or edit the source code to accurately tailor or enhance the output to meet my needs / get desired results.  What if I need to do the same with Wordpress?

Comment: If you edit the theme you will need at least a basic knowledge of php. At least the control structures and to make sure that you do not create an error. In most cases you do not need to edit your theme as long as you are fine with its options. And if you have problems there are tons of Wordpress freelancers who will help you for sure with your problems that you can't solve yourself.